# Unable to Run AudioGraph in Background Task

Tags: xamarin, uwp

I'm developing a Xamarin application. It's a glorified audio player. I created a background task for the UWP part which extends IBackgroundTask from Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;

public sealed class BackgroundServiceManager : IBackgroundTask {

    private IIpcNode m_node;//Sends/Receive message powered by LocalSettings
    private BackgroundTaskDeferral m_deferral;

    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance) {
        DebugUtils.Log("BackgroundServiceManager.Run()");

        m_deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

        m_services = new List<IBackgroundService> {
            (m_playbackService = new PlaybackService()),
            (m_smartLightService = new SmartLightsService())
        };

        this.RegisterServices();

        taskInstance.Task.Completed += OnTaskCompleted;
        taskInstance.Canceled += OnTaskCanceled;

        //Listen to messages powered by LocalSettings
        m_node.StartListening();
    }

    //...
    
}
```

I start the task using an application trigger. The background task lives in a separate project.

```
public async Task InitializeBackgroundTask() {

    var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    localSettings.Values.Clear();

    BackgroundExecutionManager.RemoveAccess();
    var accessStatus = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

    if (accessStatus == BackgroundAccessStatus.DeniedBySystemPolicy
    || accessStatus == BackgroundAccessStatus.DeniedByUser
    || accessStatus == BackgroundAccessStatus.Unspecified)
        return;

    UnregisterExistingTasks();

    var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder() {
        Name = BACKGROUND_TASK_NAME,
        TaskEntryPoint = BACKGROUND_TASK_ENTRY_POINT,
    };

    var applicationTrigger = new ApplicationTrigger();
    builder.SetTrigger(applicationTrigger);

    var registration = (BackgroundTaskRegistration)null;
    try {
        registration = builder.Register();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to register {0} background task.", BACKGROUND_TASK_NAME), ex);
    }

    registration.Completed += OnBackgroundTaskCompleted;
    registration.Progress += OnRegistrationProgress;

    this.Node.StartListening();

    var result = await applicationTrigger.RequestAsync();

    if (result != ApplicationTriggerResult.Allowed)
        throw new Exception("Unable to trigger background task.");
}
```

I have a background task declaration in my main UWP project. The task type is "general" and I provide the proper entry point.

[image: Package Manifest Declarations]

Also, the Background Media Playback capability is checked.

[image: Package Manifest Capabilities]

The task works perfectly fine, but AudioGraph doesn't generate sounds on the background task. MediaPlayer does, however. I need AudioGraph as it allows for seamless audio looping.

Here's my AudioGraph test method. I created it to isolate AudioGraph-related code:

```
public static async Task TestAudioGraph(int toneFrequency) {
    var audioFileInfo = await AudioUtils.CreateToneFile(toneFrequency);

    var settings = new AudioGraphSettings(Windows.Media.Render.AudioRenderCategory.Media);
    var createAudioGraphResult = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(settings);

    if (createAudioGraphResult.Status != AudioGraphCreationStatus.Success)
        throw new Exception(createAudioGraphResult.Status.ToString());
        
    var audioGraph = createAudioGraphResult.Graph;
    var createDeviceOutputNodeResult = await audioGraph.CreateDeviceOutputNodeAsync();

    if (createDeviceOutputNodeResult.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
        throw new Exception(createDeviceOutputNodeResult.Status.ToString());

    var deviceOutputNode = createDeviceOutputNodeResult.DeviceOutputNode;

    var storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(audioFileInfo.FileFullPath);
    var createFileInputNodeResult = await audioGraph.CreateFileInputNodeAsync(storageFile);

    if (createFileInputNodeResult.Status != AudioFileNodeCreationStatus.Success)
        throw new Exception(createFileInputNodeResult.Status.ToString());

    var fileInputNode = createFileInputNodeResult.FileInputNode;
    fileInputNode.OutgoingGain = 1;
    fileInputNode.LoopCount = Int32.MaxValue;

    fileInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(deviceOutputNode);

    fileInputNode.Start();
    audioGraph.Start();

    await Task.Delay(3000);
}
```

Sending of sound test message from foreground:

```
public async Task TestSound() {
    //Test sound on foreground first
    await Task.Run(async () => await UWPUtils.TestAudioGraph(200));

    var message = new UWPIpcMessage("TESTSOUND", null);
    await this.Node.SendMessage(message, true);
}
```

Background's handling of sound test message:

```
m_node.Subscribe("TESTSOUND", async (message) => {
    //Then test sound on background
    await Task.Run(async () => await UWPUtils.TestAudioGraph(800));
    return null;
});
```

Would you happen to know why AudioGraph doesn't work? Am I missing a setting or is this possible at all?

I look on the web and couldn't find examples or working samples, just hints that what I'm attempting is possible.

P-S: My task type is "general", because I found no way of triggering "audio" type of tasks.

Thank you

Comment: Please do NOT post code as images.  Paste and format the relevant code in the body of your post

Comment: Have you tested to verify that AudioGraph sound works, if the code is a "normal" part of running app, rather than in background task?

Comment: @Jason: It makes sense. Fixed it. Sorry, I don't use this platform often.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: Yes, I tested it using this: await Task.Run(async () => await UWPUtils.TestAudioGraph(800)); It worked. I call the same thing with a different tone frequency value before sending some message and when handling it in the task.